# Method should have "self" as first argument: pylint error for decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators, pylint

I have a decorator function:

```
def abc(f):
    def _abc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some statements
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return _abc
```

I am using `pylint` to solve linting errors. It is giving me error as:

> Method should have "self" as first argument

I am not able to find the solution for this. Anyone know this error?

Comment: Did you define this decorator function inside a class?

Comment: @mgilson: yes, it is in class. Should I move it outside of class?

Comment: You need to do `def abc(self, f):` instead of `def abc(f):`.

Comment: Depends on what the decorator is and how you want it to be used, but most likely, it shouldn't be inside the class.

Comment: @sagar.musale -- Yes, you'll probably want to move it outside of the class :-)

Comment: @algerbrex: That'd be correct if the intent was to use it like `@someinstance.abc`, but it doesn't seem likely that that was the intent. It seems more likely that the intent was to apply `@abc` to other methods of the class, before any instance exists.

Comment: @mgilson: It worked by moving that function outside of class. Thanks.

Comment: @user2357112 After looking back at the OP's code, I agree - your probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm correctly picturing what you're trying to do, move the decorating function outside of the class and the apply it inside the class using the @-notation.